# How to load image background in Magento CMS page with php-url path?

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.7

Inside a CMS block in **Magento 1.7.0.2** I am trying to get a background image

the code that I use in the HTML EDITOR for the block is this:

```
<div class="imageclass" style="background: url()">
</div>
```

Inside the url() I should place the exact url of my image.
But the problem is that if I load from WYSIWYG folder in CMS **I DON'T get a correct path**

***So what kind of path should I put into the url below ?***

```
<div class="imageclass" style="background: url()">
</div>
```

My background image is on
**/media/wysiwyg/images_cms/mybackground.png**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put in a relative or absolute URL. Also, you should put it in a class, not inline.

```
.imageclass {
  background: url(/media/wysiwyg/images_cms/mybackground.png);
}
```

See the [MDN docs for `background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to overcome a similar issue, however I needed them to be CMS editable for each page thus my backgorund could not be set in the stylesheet.

This is the method i used to get the media path:

```
<div style="background-image:url('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) ?>mybackground.png')"></div>
```

Comment: it didnt work but Thanks for the answer nick.The php though could not be parsed while I was saving the block in Magento.